# How to receive data with Scapy?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, scapy

I code a script who allows to send a packet with Scapy on IP address with a chosen destination port.

I want to receive a response of the sent packet.

For example if the packets are sent, I want to receive a response ...

I send a simple 20 bytes packets: to send the packet for instance on the 161 port I coded this

```
data ="\x14"
packet = IP(dst=adresseip)/UDP(sport=161,dport=161)/Raw(load=data) 
send(packet)
```

But how to receive a response of the sent packet?

Answer (score 3):

scapy's `sr()` function will do that for you. it sends a packet(s) and waits for response. or, after `send()`ing packet you can `sniff()` for responses. 

here's a simple example of using `sr()`:

```
>>> pingr = IP(dst="192.168.1.1")/ICMP()
>>> sr(pingr)
Begin emission:
.Finished to send 1 packets.
*
Received 2 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
(<Results: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:1 Other:0>, <Unanswered: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>)
```

Comment: How can i receive but send on layer 2?